# Python slice all except the second to last row in an array

Tags: python-3.x, slice

I know how to slice an array with all except a row at the beggining or end of an array but not an array with just one row in the middle (like the second to the last row) missing. How would I do this?

Comment: You question isn't clear enough. Could you give us an example? Like a input list and the expected result. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove an item from the middle using slices, you will almost always need to concatenate two different slices, one for the items before and one for the items after.
If `n` is the index of the item you want to remove you can generally do

```
new_list = old_list[:n] + old_list[n+1:]
```